# Setup rails 7 and React as one App using jsbundling-rails on windows

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, jsbundling-rails

Following there [github page](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails)

**All have done earlier**

1. rails new hello-world -j esbuild
2. bundle add jsbundling-rails
3. When I run rails javascript:install:esbuild

**I got the following errors below**

[image]

**Under their FAQ:**

Is there a work-around for lack of glob syntax on Windows?

The default build script for esbuild relies on the app/javascript/*.* glob pattern to compile multiple entry points automatically. This glob pattern is not available by default on Windows, so you need to change the build script in package.json to manually list the entrypoints you wish to compile.

**below is my package.json**

[image]

**How would I modify it to work on Windows OS?**

Comment: What command lead you to the above error ? Because with `rails new hello-world -j esbuild` your app should be esbuild ready. (with jsbundling-rails). Also why Webpack, do you plan to use two bundlers alltogether ?

Comment: rails javascript:install:esbuild

Comment: check out my recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76237989/bundling-directory-structures-in-esbuild-for-a-rails-7-application  I believe this solves the problem.  And your question is not easily found as the title doesn't make sense.