# Bundling directory structures in esbuild for a Rails 7 application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, esbuild, jsbundling-rails

How do I import Javascript with directories?

I've set up `jsbundling-rails` using the `esbuild` bundler for a Rails 7 project that was previously using sprockets to handle all assets.  It appears that I've set it up correctly, because I can load JS files by directly referencing the file.

Though I've got a lot of files and I even want to impose some human logic on the structure of the javascript.

To do this, I want to split up some javascript in directories, like this:

```
app
- assets
-- javascript
--- some.js
--- some_more.js
---- base
----- some_other.js
----- some_way_other.js
```

I'm able to load all of this js with my `application.js` at `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file, like this:

```
import "./some"
import "./some_more"
import "./base/some_other"
import "./base/some_way_other"
```

the console log responds with:

[image]

but I want to be able to load/bundle this JS using this syntax:

```
import "./some"
import "./some_more"
import "./base"
```

but from the js watcher, I get:

```
15:39:22 js.1   | [watch] build started (change: "app/javascript/application.js")
15:39:22 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "./base"
15:39:22 js.1   |
15:39:22 js.1   |     app/javascript/application.js:14:7:
15:39:22 js.1   |       14 │ import "./base"
15:39:22 js.1   |          ╵        ~~~~~~~~
15:39:22 js.1   |
15:39:22 js.1   | 1 error
15:39:22 js.1   | [watch] build finished
```

My Procfile.dev

```
web: unset PORT && /root/.rbenv/shims/thin start -C config/thin_development.yml
js: yarn build --watch
```

I mean, is this even possible?  I used to be able to do this with sprockets, but it doesn't seem like I can with esbuild.  Or should I just be sticking with a massive application.js file and manually import each javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to customize esbuild with a configuration file known as `esbuild.config.js` and to utilize the plugin `esbuild-rails` created by Chris at GoRails, found at https://github.com/excid3/esbuild-rails.

`esbuild.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const rails = require('esbuild-rails')

const watch = process.argv.includes("--watch") && {
  onRebuild(error) {
    if (error) console.error("[watch] build failed", error);
    else console.log("[watch] build finished");
  },
};

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["application.js"],
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  watch: watch,
  write: true,
  loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  publicPath: 'assets',
  target: 'es6',
  // custom plugins will be inserted is this array
  plugins: [rails()],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

Usage in `application.js`

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
const application = Application.start()

import './meta/jquery'
import './meta/ajax'
import './controllers'

import libraries from "./libraries/*.js"
import custom_files from "./custom/*.js"

libraries.forEach((controller) => {
    application.register(controller.name, controller.module.default)
})

custom_files.forEach((controller) => {
    application.register(controller.name, controller.module.default)
})
```